# Print last matching line?

Tags: bash, awk

Using `awk`, I would like to print the last matching line of a file.
I would like only the matching line itself, not any range of lines.
I can use a command like this

```sh
awk '/foo/' bar.txt
```

However this will print all matching lines, not just the last one.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can save the value in a variable and then print it after processing the whole file:

```
awk '/foo/ {a=$0} END{print a}' file
```

#### Test

```
$ cat file
foo1
foo2
foo3
4
5
$ awk '/foo/ {a=$0} END{print a}' file
foo3
```

Comment: Awesome solution!

Answer (score 6):

reverse the file and find the *first* match.

```
tac file | awk '/foo/ {print; exit}'
```

Comment: This assumes that no earlier context is required in order to determine which lines to print.

Comment: Hmm, just occurred to me you could also do this with `tac file | grep -m1 foo` so that MAY be slightly better as it's briefer and IMHO no less clear. Won't work with all greps though, it might be GNU grep specific.

Comment: `tac $file | grep $pattern | tac | tail -n $N` -- to print last N matched lines preserving order

Answer (score 6):

`sed` solution:

```
sed -n '/foo/h;$!b;g;p' bar.txt
```

Place the matching `regex` in hold buffer and branch out. Keep doing this until end of file. When the end of file is reached, grab the line from hold space and place it on pattern space. Print pattern space.

Answer (score 5):

The command `tail` allows you to retreive the last `n` lines of an input stream. You can pipe your `awk` output into `tail` in order to trim off everything except the last line:

```
awk '/foo/' bar.txt | tail -1
```

Comment: Without a pipe, store the line and print it in `END`.

Answer (score 2):

You can assign values to variables and print them at the end of processing both the lines and their number.

File:

```
$ cat file
foo1
foo2
foo3
4
5
```

Command:

```
$ awk '/foo/ {a=$0;n=NR} END{print n, a}' file
3 foo3
```